# Why doesn't this work for integrating $x^2e^{-ax^2}$ by parts?

Tags: integration

So I'm trying to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{   }x^2e^{-ax^2}dx$ by parts with the formula

$$\int{udv} =  uv  - \int{vdu}      $$

I'm selecting

$$u = x^2$$
$$du = 2xdx$$
$$ v = \sqrt{\pi/\lambda} $$
$$    dv = e^{-ax^2} dx$$

This gives me

$$\Biggr|_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^2 \sqrt{\pi/\lambda}   }  - \int_{-\infty}^\infty{   } \sqrt{\pi/\lambda} *  2x dx $$

Which equates to $0$.

This particular integral has been asked about before and I know how to solve it through integration by parts the "right way", but my question is why isn't the above a "legal move"? I solved another integral by evaluating the Gaussian integral during an integration by parts set-up just like this and it gave me the correct answer. I know I'm wrong, just not why.

Edit: My apologies, made an error in the type-up that made the whole thing nonsense, had $x^2$ as a factor of $dv$ by mistake.

Comment: I think it must be $$a>0$$!

Comment: Your $\;v'\;$ and thus your $\;v\;$ *must be actual functions*', not merely **numbers**! If $\;v'=k\in\Bbb R\;$ , then clearly $\;v=kx\;$ ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Why do they have to be functions?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I don't understand what you're saying here.

Comment: @Bookie Because otherwise you get something trivial...and also because then your $\;uv'\;$ is **not** what you have inside the original integral...

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't understand why this is the case.  When I applied the exact same method to solving $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{   }xe^{-ax^2}dx$, it gives me the correct answer. If this method is illegal then how do you even go about solving $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{   }xe^{-ax^2}dx$? Also, could you explain to me a bit more? You're saying you can never use an expression for $dv$ which integrates to a constant rather than a function?

Comment: $$\int_a^budv=(uv)\Big|_a^b-\int_a^bvdu$$You have to apply the limits to the aggregate $uv$, not to $u,v$ separately

Comment: If $v=k$ is a constant function, then $dv=0 \, dx$ (obviously, since the derivative of a constant function is zero)...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the brief explanations here, I understand why this doesn't work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\;\alpha >0\;$ , put

$$\begin{cases}u=x,&u'=1\\{}\\
v'=xe^{-\alpha x^2},&-\frac1{2\alpha}e^{-\alpha x^2}\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2}dx=\overbrace{-\left.\frac1{2\alpha}xe^{-\alpha x^2}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty}^{=0}+\frac1{2\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}dx=$$

$$=\frac1{2\alpha^{3/2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d(\sqrt\alpha\,x)\,e^{-\left(\sqrt\alpha\,x\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\alpha^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for going out of your way to demonstrate the correct solution, I appreciate that. Your comment also makes sense to me now after a moment's thought on it, thanks.