# Doubt in integration by parts

Tags: integration

The integration by parts formula (in NCERT) is given as:$$
\int f(x) g(x) = f(x)\int g(x)- \int f'(x)\int g(x)dx$$
Can it be successfully applied to $$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2} dx=x^2\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x^2}-\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} 2x\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$$$$
=x^2 \sqrt{\pi/\alpha}-(x^2 \sqrt{\pi/\alpha})|^{\infty}_{-\infty}$$ I could get the required answer by using $$\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} udv= uv|^{\infty}_{-\infty} -\int  ^{\infty}_{-\infty} vdu.$$ **I want to know why the ncert formula fails,if i take $f(x)= x^2$ and use the limits.Please tell me where im making a mistake.**

Comment: In particular, to apply that formula, you should choose $f,g$ so that differentiation of $f$ is easy, and integration of $g$ is easy.  Otherwise you replace one integral by a (possibly harder) integral.  The formula does not "fail" when you take $f(x) =x^2$.  It yields something that is correct, but not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula with $g(x)=xe^{-\alpha x^{2}}$ and $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{bmatrix}f \\ \mathrm dg\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\xe^{-\alpha x^2}\end{bmatrix}\implies\int x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx=-\dfrac{x\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x^2}}{2\alpha}+\dfrac{1}{2\alpha}\int e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx\\ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt{a}x\right)}{4a^{3/2}}-\dfrac{x\mathrm{e}^{-ax^2}}{2a}\Biggl|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\alpha^{3/2}}
$$

Comment: sir can u show me how the evaluation goes if i use f(x)=x^2.I wanted to know why ncert method fails if i do like this!.

Comment: Have a look at this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089298/why-doesnt-this-work-for-integrating-x2e-ax2-by-parts?rq=1